# Adding Additional rows to pandas dataframe to capture residual value while retaining the top 2 for each

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'State':['am','am','am','am','am','am','am','am','am','fg','fg','fg','fg','fg','fg','fg'],
'PC':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],
'Party':['alpha','beta','delta','yellow','alpha','beta','blue','pink','gamma','alpha','beta','kappa','alpha','gamma','kappa','lambda'],
'Votes':[10,15,50,5,11,2,5,4,60,3,1,70,12,34,52,43]
})
```

I want to add a Total column, which will contain the sums of the votes for each PC. Note that the PC can have the same name (e.g. 'A' above in two different states 'am' and 'fg', so we want to sum them separately, since they are different pc). This I do as follows

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby(['State','PC']).Votes.transform('sum')
```

After that I want to retain only the top two 'Party' by 'Vote' for each combination of 'State' and 'PC', except when the top two does not include 'beta'. In that case I want a third row for 'beta'. And, then I want to capture any remaining 'Vote' count in a new row with 'Party' as 'REST' as needed.

In sum I want the output as follows:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({
'State':['am','am','am','am','am','am','am','fg','fg','fg','fg','fg','fg'],
'PC':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','A','A','A'],
'Party':['delta','beta','REST','gamma','alpha','REST','beta','kappa','alpha','beta','kappa','lambda','REST'],
'Votes':[50,15,15,60,11,9,2,70,3,1,52,43,46],
'Total':[80,80,80,82,82,82,82,74,74,74,141,141,141]
})
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `df.groupby(['State','PC']).Votes.transform('sum')` does what you want, not sure what  the issue is, and where the thing about "beta" and whatnot comes in...

Comment: @coldspeed I am thinking he is need combine the rest value besides two 2 , if top two do not contain beta, he want to add beta to it . :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben Kudos to you for doing some spectacular mind reading to understand what was required. ++

Comment: @coldspeed I was confused when I read through the question , until I look at the df_out .

Comment: @Wen-Ben It was confusing to me too, because Party column notwithstanding, the output of Total is exactly what they would get by a simple groupby and transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `groupby` `head`, and combine others with `groupby` + `agg` , then `concat` back , here if the first two do not include beta, I am adding that row back `s1`

```
s1=df.sort_values('Votes').groupby(['PC','State']).tail(2)
s2=df[~df.index.isin(s1.index)]
s1=pd.concat([s1,s2.loc[s2.Party=='beta']])
s2=s2[~s2.index.isin(s1.index)].groupby(['PC','State']).agg({'Votes':'sum','Total':'first'}).assign(Party='REST')
yourdf=pd.concat([s1,s2.reset_index()],sort=True).sort_values(['PC','State'])
yourdf
Out[517]: 
   PC   Party State  Total  Votes
1   A    beta    am     80     15
2   A   delta    am     80     50
0   A    REST    am     80     15
4   B   alpha    am     82     11
8   B   gamma    am     82     60
5   B    beta    am     82      2
1   B    REST    am     82      9
9   C   alpha    fg     74      3
11  C   kappa    fg     74     70
10  C    beta    fg     74      1
15  D  lambda    fg    141     43
14  D   kappa    fg    141     52
2   D    REST    fg    141     46
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Question: do you think `df.drop(s1.index)` is faster than `df[~df.index.isin(s1.index)]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I think that should be succinct than what I used right now

Comment: It is giving me a KeyError on this line: s2=s2[~s2.index.isin(s1.index)].groupby(['PC','State']).agg({'Votes':'sum','Total':'first'}).assign(Party='REST')

KeyError: 'Total'

Comment: @AlhpaDelta you should run your own line before running my solution `df['Total'] = df.groupby(['State','PC']).Votes.transform('sum')
`

Comment: how do we modify this to include 'gamma' besides 'beta' every time? I tried s1 = pd.concat([s1,s2.loc[s2.Party in ['beta','gamma']]]).sort_values(['PC','State','Votes'])
but it gives me ValueError

Comment: @AlhpaDelta change in to isin